# Асинхронная работа с БД на C#

Tags: c#, база-данных

Есть программа, принимающая в асинхронном режиме запросы от клиентов. Запросов достаточно большое количество и все они требуют подключения к БД (чтение, запись). В случает одновременно нескольких запросов возникают ошибки.

```
Возникло System.InvalidOperationException: "An operation is already in progress."
Возникло System.InvalidOperationException: "Reset() called on connector with state Executing"
Возникло System.InvalidOperationException: "No row is available"
```

Как лучше реализовать асинхронную работу? Первое что приходит на ум - ManualResetEvent, но тогда работа с базой станет синхронной, что может повлиять на производительность. Есть ли какие-нибудь другие способы решения данной проблемы?
Код:

```
try
    {
        this.connection.Open();

        NpgsqlCommand com = new NpgsqlCommand(queryString, this.connection);
        NpgsqlDataReader DataReader = com.ExecuteReader();

        while (DataReader.Read())
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        this.connection.Close();
    }
```

Соединение создается у меня в конструкторе:

```
NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder mysqlCSB = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder();

mysqlCSB.Host = settings.Server;
mysqlCSB.Database = settings.Database;
mysqlCSB.Username = settings.User;
mysqlCSB.Password = settings.Password;

this.connection.ConnectionString = mysqlCSB.ConnectionString;
```

Надо этот код перенести в функцию выше?

Comment: Проблемный код покажите для начала.

Comment: И как вы этот код запускаете? Одновременно из нескольких потоков?

Comment: Да. Это функция Select

Comment: То есть у вас расшаренный connection между потоками? о_О Так нельзя, открывайте новый connection в каждом потоке. Иначе закрывая его в одном потоке, вы выдёргиваете табуретку из-под другого потока.

Comment: Подумайте в сторону использования метода BeginExecuteReader или ExecuteReaderAsync, если они реализованы в вашем драйвере.

Comment: Таких методов в драйвере нету

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем методе доступа к данным достаточно создавать новый объект и использовать  Pooling (добавить в строчку конфигурации `Pooling=true;`):

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = null;
try
{
    conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();

    var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(queryString, conn);
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //...
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (conn != null)
        conn.Close();
}
```

**Вариант 2**

В каждом потоке создавать свой экземпляр вашего класса доступа к данным, в котором реализован этот метод `Select`.

**Pooling**

Операции открытия и закрытия подключения к бд довольно затратные. Если их дергать при каждом запросе, то это сильно замедлит работу. С включенным пулингом эти операции прозрачно меняются на виртуальные, которые не создают и закрывают реальное подключение, а лишь берут открытое соединение из пула соединений и возвращают его обратно. При этом соблюдается правило, что одно соединение отдается только одному вызывающему. Это сильно экономит время вызова, а для разработчика предоставляет удобный способ работы.

Размером пула открытых соединений можно управлять. В нем задаются минимальное, максимальное и количество новых соединений, которые нужно открыть, если соединений больше нет.

В пуле так же предусмотрено закрытие соединений, которые долго не использовались, чтобы не тратить системный ресурсы клиента и бд.

Comment: а что означает атрибут Pooling?

Comment: Добавил про pooling.